# Como mostrar apenas pastas no JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um `JFileChooser` e preciso que ele mostre apenas as pastas, porém eu só consigo fazer mostrar no minimo um tipo de arquivo ou mostrar todos os tipos. 
Segue código exemplo em que eu faço a restrição para um tipo de arquivo:

```
package NewClass;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    FileNameExtensionFilter fileFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF", "pdf");
    jFileChooser1.setFileFilter(fileFilter);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jFileChooser1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jFileChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jFileChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JFileChooser jFileChooser1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Nesse exemplo eu restringi a visualização apenas para arquivos pdf.

Código em que eu mostro todos tipos de arquivos:

```
package NewClass;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jFileChooser1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jFileChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jFileChooser1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JFileChooser jFileChooser1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Nesse exemplo não fiz nenhuma restrição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta definir o modo de seleção para apenas pastas:

```
jFileChooser1.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

- Exibição da pasta sem nenhum filtro utilizando seu codigo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Exibiçao de pasta utilizando a linha mencionada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso que eu estava precisando, obrigado.

Comment: @PedroAfonso Se a resposta solucionou sua dúvida, você pode aceitá-la. [**Veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/28595) como aceitar uma resposta.

Comment: Não tava dando pra aceitar, tava aparecendo que eu precisava esperar um tempo.